# Exponents in C and Python giving different answers

Tags: python, c, math

Trying to do Fermat's Little Theorem and noticed it wasn't working in C so I tried it in Python and it worked fine.

**Fermat's Little Theorem**

> https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsLittleTheorem.html

The answer is supposed to give me a 1 but I'm getting 13.

**Python exponent(working)**

```
prime_num = 13**(17-1)

>665416609183179841
prime_num%17 = 1
```

**C exponent(not working)**

```
double prime_num = pow(13,17-1)

>665416609183179904
fmod(prime_num,17) = 13
```

Comment: C's `pow` is floating-point based, so there is a natural loss of precision in the calculation.  For smaller numbers it is not noticable, but you'll start to see it in larger numbers like your example.

Comment: powf is for floats, pow is for doubles but I just found out the solution I should've been using powl

Comment: Even the longest primitive type will be far too small for anything except the smallest RSA examples. If you forgo the built-in `pow()` function and write your own [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) method you can have much larger examples while still using only primitive types. For real world-sized RSA examples you will need a bignum library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score 1):

In C the pow() function takes and returns double precision floating point values which are approximations.

In Python the ** operator does the operation using Python integers, grow in size (memory used to hold the value).  If you forced the numbers to be floating points before the operation you'd probably get the same results.

In C you could try writing a different power function that worked with uint64_t (unsigned long long) and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use long long if you want the precision.  The problem is there is no pow so it is down to simple multiplication.

```
long long n, val;
int ii;

n = 13LL;
val = n;
for (ii = 2; ii < 17; ++ii)
    val *= n;
printf("%lld\n", val);
printf("%lld\n", val % 17LL);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I should've been using `powl()` which returns a long double instead of a double and I also should've been using `fmodl()` which returns the remainder that has a long double type.

C code working

```
long double prime_num = powl(13,17-1);
>665416609183179841
fmodl(primen_num,17);
>1
```